# How to dispose user control from mfc++

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have mfc++ project and when i close my user control in c# COM dll. Memory is not decreasing and when i open again memory going increasing more.

So How to dispose my user control? Here my dispose method

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl,IDisposable
{
 private IntPtr handle;
private Component component = new Component();
private bool disposed = false;



public UserControl1(IntPtr handle)
{
  this.handle = handle;
}
public void Dispose()
{
Dispose(true);

GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{

 if (!this.disposed)
{
 if (disposing)
 {
    component.Dispose();
  }

 CloseHandle(handle);
 handle = IntPtr.Zero;

 disposed = true;

}
} 

~UserControl1()
{

GC.Collect();
Dispose(false);

 }
 }
```

Comment: Choose c++ or c# not both.

Comment: Maybe by calling `Dispose(true)` in the dtor?